# how to set time zone for mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongoid for my rails app.

I want to set time zone for mongoid.

I tried with this in application.rb

```
config.mongoid.time_zone  = 'Kolkata'
```

but no luck. I also tried with this

```
use_utc: false
use_activesupport_time_zone: true
```

still it uses default time zone UTC.

rails 3.0.10

mongoid 2.2.4

please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in application.rb like this

```
config.time_zone = 'Kolkata'
```

and in mongoid.yml

```
use_activesupport_time_zone: true
```

Comment: thanks abhas for your quick response. i already configured as above but still mongoid uses default time zone. is it working fine with you?

Comment: in model use field type as Time not DateTime.